# SQL Developer Export HTML Styles

Tags: html, css, oracle-sqldeveloper

The most recent version (4.1.1.19) of SQL Developer has a new, black, column header row which is not very appealing.

The styles for the exported html file are saved as a `<style>` block in the `<head>` tag in the file.

There appear to be no settings in SQL Developer preferences which will allow changing of the colors or fonts of the export of a query result to HTML. There are also no configuration files which contain this information or any files which might be included in the generation of the export file.

How can I change the style block of the html exported query result?

EDIT: This may not be possible. After some digging, I found the file in which the style is created. It is contained in `$sqldeveloper_dir/sqldeveloper/lib/oracle.dbtools-common.jar` in the file `oracle/dbtools/raptor/format/HTMLFormatter.class`. The style block is a hard coded entity within this file:

```
public class HTMLFormatter
extends ResultsFormatter {
    public static final String TYPE = "HTML";
    public static final String EXT = "htm";
    public static final String KEY_REC_TERM = "EXPORT_HTM_REC_TERM";
    private boolean _result = true;
    private static final String HEADER = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\n<head>\n  <meta charset='@@ENCODING@@'>\n  \n  <title>Responsive Table</title>\n  \n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n\n  \n  <style>\n  * { \n    margin: 0; \n    padding: 0; \n  }\n  body { \n    font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif; \n  }\n  \n  /* \n  Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops \n  */\n  table { \n    width: 100%; \n    border-collapse: collapse; \n  }\n  /* Zebra striping */\n  tr:nth-of-type(odd) { \n    background: #eee; \n  }\n  th { \n    background: #333; \n    color: white; \n    font-weight: bold; \n  }\n  td, th { \n    padding: 6px; \n    border: 1px solid #9B9B9B; \n    text-align: left; \n  }\n  @media \n  only screen and (max-width: 760px),\n  (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {\n    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { display: block; }\n    thead tr { position: absolute;top: -9999px;left: -9999px;}\n    tr { border: 1px solid #9B9B9B; }\n    td { border: none;border-bottom: 1px solid #9B9B9B; position: relative;padding-left: 50%; }\n    \n    td:before { position: absolute;top: 6px;left: 6px;width: 45%; padding-right: 10px; white-space: nowrap;}\n    \n    /*\n    Label the data\n    */";
    private static final String HEADER_PART2 = "  }\n  \n  /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */\n  @media only screen\n  and (min-device-width : 320px)\n  and (max-device-width : 480px) {\n    body { \n      padding: 0; \n      margin: 0; \n      width: 320px; }\n    }\n  \n  /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */\n  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {\n    body { \n      width: 495px; \n    }\n  }\n  \n  </style>\n  <!--<![endif]-->\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n\nlsearch = function(){\n  //this.term = document.getElementById('S').value.toUpperCase();\n  var s = document.getElementById('search').value.toLowerCase();\n  rows = document.getElementById('data').getElementsByTagName('TR');\n  for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){\n    if (s ==\"\" ){\n      rows[i].style.display ='';\n    } else if ( rows[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) != -1 ) {\n      rows[i].style.display ='';\n    } else {\n      rows[i].style.display ='none';\n    }\n  }\n  this.time = false;\n}\n\n</script>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div><input type=\"text\" size=\"30\" maxlength=\"1000\" value=\"\" id=\"search\" onkeyup=\"lsearch();\" /><input type=\"button\" value=\"Go\" onclick=\"lsearch();\"/> </div>";

    public HTMLFormatter() {
        super("HTML", "HTML File", "htm");
    }
...
```

Unfortunately, this is a compiled class and decompilation->edit->recompile has not been successful due to dependencies and oracle not having released a build project (to my knowledge).